# Jenkins/Groovy: How to pass named parameters and closures to the same method?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a shared library method with this signature:

```
call(Map kwargs, String image_name, String version, Closure closure)
```

And I'm calling it like so:

```
dockerBuildWith("go-build", "latest", image_context: "build", 
                changesets: ["build/Dockerfile"]) {
  ...
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: dockerBuildWith.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [[image_context:build, changesets:[build/Dockerfile]], go-build, ...]
>
> Possible solutions: call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), any(), run(), run(), dump()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put `def` in front of the `call()` definition.